# Python, Pandas, and Pico: Unable to import Pandas, but NumPy is no problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've managed to construct a simple app utilizing the Pico framework (https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico). My frontend is connecting to my backend without any difficulties. Below is my Python file, which at the moment simply returns/renders a string, using a client-side input value, "name".

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
import pico
import numpy as np

# import sklearn
# import pandas as pd
from api2 import aloha

from pico import PicoApp

@pico.expose()
def hello(name):

   a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
   # a = np.arrange('data', 'field').reshape(3,5)

return "hello %s, %s" %(name, a)

app = PicoApp()
app.register_module(__name__)
```

(It also returns a NumPy array, simply because I'm testing what I can import into the file.)

All my packages are installed just fine, via Anaconda in `/site-packages`, which is in the `python3.6` directory.

Oddly, the app runs fine; it can import NumPy. It breaks, however, when I try to import Pandas or SKLearn. I've tried manually copying and pasting NumPy into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, which actually breaks the app. But NumPy works in the app when it is *only* located in Anaconda's `/site-packages`.

I've tried altering `app.register(__name__)` to `app.register('api')`, which is the name of the Python file (`api.py`), based on another Question/Answer here. I've also tried reinstalling Pandas with `sudo -H pip install pandas`, but all the requirements are already satisfied.

This is the error that is thrown when I try to include Pandas in `api.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pico/server.py", line 31, in <module>
    app = import_string(module_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 443, in import_string
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 431, in import_string
    module = import_string(module_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 443, in import_string
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/utils.py", line 418, in import_string
    __import__(import_name)
  File "./api.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    'this pandas version'.format(_np_version))
werkzeug.utils.ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'api.app'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'api' not found.

Original exception:

ImportStringError: import_string() failed for 'api'. Possible reasons are:

- missing __init__.py in a package;
- package or module path not included in sys.path;
- duplicated package or module name taking precedence in sys.path;
- missing module, class, function or variable;

Debugged import:

- 'api' not found.

Original exception:

ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.9.0
your numpy version is 1.8.0rc1.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.9.0 to use this pandas version
```

When I run `which python`, it points to `/Users/richardscheiwe/anaconda3/bin/python`. Also, I have NumPy v.1.15 installed, and I can't find any other NumPy folder(s). When I try moving a version of NumPy to `Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, I get this error:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

I guess I need to somehow point the app's Python to Anaconda's Python 3.6 version, but I don't know how to do that. Pico is also available in Anaconda's `/site-packages` directory, but it isn't pointing there.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've scoured StackOverflow and GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention how you are starting the pico app but I assume you are doing like this:

`python -m pico.server api`

In this case it will simply use whatever `python` is in your path. If it is python3 in `/Users/richardscheiwe/anaconda3/bin/python` but you are getting errors referring to `/Library/Python/2.7/` then there is some problem with your anaconda installation/paths in your environment.

There is nothing different with pico to running a plain python script but I suggest you create a simplified script without pico (literally just import `pandas`) to work out your environment issues with simpler error messages.

Comment: Great, thank you. I figured in the end that it's an installation thing regarding Pandas/Anaconda. Appreciated.

Comment: With the correctly set, Pico is running perfectly, and it's able to read Pandas dfs. Very cool framework!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly the error seems to come from trying to use a version of NumPy built for running on python 2.6 while your app is running using Python3.

Try removing NumPy using; "sudo pip uninstall numpy" and then use "pip -H install Numpy" to try reinstalling it and seeing if it correctly finds the Python3 version of Numpy

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Ran into this issue, now: 

`The directory '/Users/richardscheiwe/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: Try removing it using Anaconda; "conda remove numpy"

Then Install using sudo pip install -h numpy